# Laravel, struggling to reproduce query with the query builder

Tags: php, laravel

I have got the following query, which returns 44 rows:

```sql
SELECT id, IF(r.make, CONCAT(makes.description, ': ', r.make), 0) AS make, IF(r.model, models.description, 0) AS model, r.text, r.h1_tag, r.title, r.keywords, r.description, r.website_search_path_id, r.website_vehicle_type_id 
FROM website_results_text r 
LEFT JOIN vehicle_makes makes ON makes.code = r.make
LEFT JOIN vehicle_models models ON models.code = r.model AND models.make = r.make
WHERE r.website_id = 1966
```

The results are similar to as follows, not included all rows and excluded columns that don't really matter.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | make       | model        | text     | h1_tag     | title    |
_____________________________________________________________________
| 192| 0          | 0            | test     | test       | test     |
| 193| Fiat:24    | 0            | test     | test       | test     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below is the query that I have got so far, as you can see i'm missing the IF statements for if there is no make returned from the `vehicle_makes` table.

```
$resultsText = ResultsText::where([ 'website_id' => $website->id ])
    ->join('vehicle_makes', 'website_results_text.make', '=', 'vehicle_makes.code')
    ->join('vehicle_models', 'website_results_text.model', '=', 'vehicle_models.code')
    ->select(
        'vehicle_makes.description AS make',
        'vehicle_models.description AS model',
        'website_results_text.text',
        'website_results_text.h1_tag',
        'website_results_text.title',
        'website_results_text.keywords',
        'website_results_text.website_search_path_id',
        'website_results_text.website_vehicle_type_id'
    )->get();
```

Comment: In most cases, where you see a `JOIN` in a SQL query, you should be using an Eloquent relationship. The resulting queries will be different, but far easier to work with in Laravel.

Comment: @ceejayoz I forgot about that! Let me adjust my code, will update post.

Comment: You can use selectRaw and write your select as in your query

Comment: Also should probably modify those joins to `leftJoin`